# What is the name of this book, covering character history generation?

Tags: product-identification, books, generator

Recently, over a text-chat session, my game master ran through a process of detailing my character's history, using a product she never named.  My GM is currently unavailable to me, so I cannot simply ask her what the product was.

The product was apparently a number of random tables, detailing things like ('you' refers to your character):

- The status of your parents (both alive, one dead, both dead) (a roll of 3 from 1d4 resulted in my mother being dead, but my father still being alive.)
- If your parents remarried (1d6=3 Mother had previously left my character's father and remarried)
- How many siblings you have, and their relative age to you (1d12=6 2 younger siblings)
- Your romantic relationships (are you in a relationship) (1d6=6 some variant of me being in a relationship but unfaithful)
- If you have children (1d4=3 I have 2 children)
- Your family's status (are they criminals? bankers?) (1d20=9 family is one of bankers)
- How you dress yourself (1d20=4 fancy or formal wear)
- 'Notable items of wear' (see the image)
- How people would describe you (1d20=9 'Easy going')
- Your education (1d10=7 Privately tutored)
- Sources of secondary income (1d20=19 'Work agent' whatever that means, =5 independently wealthy)
- The languages you speak, and your level of literacy (1d20=15, 2d6=3,6 speak+read 2 non-common languages, speak common with an accent, illiterate in common)
- Your personality (1d100=60 "mean")
- Secrets in your character history (1d100=95: secret: left to die)
- The sound of your voice

[image: The only actual table I have an image of]

The setting we are playing in is a custom fantasy setting, using Dungeon World for rules.  I have no idea if it is a Dungeon World product, a product for another system, or a generic product.

The image I referenced was an area-capture from a scan of the page.  I don't know if my GM had scanned the entire book, or just that page, but she sent me that image (she actually sent me the imgur link that I embedded in this question).

I managed to find someone with a copy of Central Casting: Heroes of Legend (first and second editions, amazingly), and I am positive that it is not that book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My GM finally got up and around some today.  The book is called [Background & Details Kit](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/108091/Background--Details-Kit?affiliate_id=202622) by [Ennead Games](http://enneadgames.com/)